# Analyze code with SonarLint for IntelliJ

Tags: sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

i have installed latest SonarLint version 2 for IntelliJ and configure it to work with my SonarQube server version 5.2. i also bind SonarLint to my project in SonarQube.
When i'm trying to run analysis for one file or for all project, i'm getting below error:

```
Error running SonarLint analysis
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintAnalysisConfigurator.analyzeModule(SonarLintAnalysisConfigurator.java:90)
    at org.sonarlint.intellij.analysis.SonarLintTask.run(SonarLintTask.java:93)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:152)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.a(CoreProgressManager.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:402)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

SonarLint 2.0 is broken in IDEA 14.
A bug fix will be released soon.

I've just created a ticket: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLI-62.